# Rails ActiveRecord self.___ vs @____

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I think this this is a pretty stupid question but I just confused myself

I have several has_many defined. I can reference them in an instance method by saying self.------- If I try to reference via @------ I get nil. Is it just that because it's an ActiveRecord object that it's not available as an instance variable inside the class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not set as instance variables, they are methods. Same as for your properties, you should always access them like this:

```
self.property
self.read_attribute(:property)
self.write_attribute(:property, value)
```

They could even be instance variables at the end, but this is an implementation detail and you should always call the code over the **well known** interface, which is the methods.

Answer (score 1):

associations are methods not instance variables.